# python: dictionary and numpy.array issue

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary with arrays (same length) associated to strings. My goal is to create a new dictionary with the same keys but cutting the arrays, keeping only the elements I need. I wrote a function to do it but the problem is that it returns a dictionary with the same array (correct cut length) associated to every key, while the print command i put to control show the correct association. Here's the function:

```
def extract_years(dic,initial_year,final_year):

    dic_extr = {}
    l = numpy.size(dic[dic.keys()[0]])

    if final_year != 2013 : 
        a = numpy.zeros((final_year - initial_year)*251)
    elif final_year == 2013 :
        a = numpy.zeros(l - (initial_year-1998)*251)

    for i in range(0,len(dic)):
        #print i
        for k in range (0,numpy.size(a)):
            a[k] = dic[dic.keys()[i]][(initial_year-1998)*251 + k]          
            #print k

        dic_extr[dic.keys()[i]] = a
        print dic.keys()[i]
        print dic_extr[dic.keys()[i]]


    print dic_extr.keys()
    print dic_extr
    return dic_extr
```

as I said, `print dic_extr[dic.keys()[i]]` shows the correct results while the final `print dic_extr` shows a dictionary with the same array associated to every key.

Comment: Please fix indentation.

Comment: Could you give an example of the function call which have an unexpected result, and with the result that you would expect?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GSncW5DE
i pasted the terminal output here as the dictionary has more than 300 elements and the arrays very long. As you can see the first prints are the 
    `print dic.keys()[i]
         print dic_extr[dic.keys()[i]]`
while the last is `print dic_extr` which is completely different, i just expected the whole first print all together in the new dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, every object is a pointer. So, you should have to create a new instance of `a` for each iteration of the outer `for` loop. You could do this, for example, initializing the `a` array inside of that loop, like this:

```
def extract_years(dic,initial_year,final_year):

    dic_extr = {}
    l = numpy.size(dic[dic.keys()[0]])

    for i in range(0,len(dic)):

        if final_year != 2013 : 
            a = numpy.zeros((final_year - initial_year)*251)
        elif final_year == 2013 :
            a = numpy.zeros(l - (initial_year-1998)*251)

        for k in range (0,numpy.size(a)):
            a[k] = dic[dic.keys()[i]][(initial_year-1998)*251 + k]          
            #print k

        dic_extr[dic.keys()[i]] = a
        print dic.keys()[i]
        print dic_extr[dic.keys()[i]]


    print dic_extr.keys()
    print dic_extr
    return dic_extr
```

Perhaps this is not the most elegant solution, but I think that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you ran into the typical problem of mutability and pythons way to define variables:

1. You define `a` to be mutable type by using `numpy.zeros()`.
2. Then you make `a` have a certain values in it, but you actually have a pointer to a list of pointers, pointing to the actuall values.
3. By using `dic_extr[dic.keys()[i]] = a`you copy this pointer into the `dic_extr` array, not the list of pointers.
4. Then you change the objects that the pointer list refers to.
5. By using `dic_extr[dic.keys()[i]] = a`you copy the pointer to the list of pointers into the `dic_extr` array, again not the pointer list itself.

In the end both pointer point to the same pointer list. Easy example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = a
b[0] = 10
print(a) # returns [10, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can use `dic_extr[dic.keys()[i]] = a[:]` to actually make a copy of a.

[Here is also a nice explaination to mutability in python.](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2001-February/003787.html)

Comment: Does it still refer to the same thing or what is the problem?

Comment: just same output